# Установка header'ов в JSP-странице

Tags: веб-программирование, java, http, jsp

Можно ли в коде JSP-страницы установить значение header'а Content-Disposition **без использования скриптлетов** (т. е. без конструкций вроде `<% response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "value"); %>`)?

Comment: вы используете jsp без сервлетов ?

Comment: С сервлетами. Но интересует именно установка header'ов на странице.

Comment: Ну.. можно наверно попробовать через [CGI](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/CGI-with-Java.html) сделать, но это то ещё извращение)

И это уже будет не jsp.

Comment: мне почему то кажется что так сделать нельзя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изучение документации показало, что подобное невозможно. Всем спасибо.